# Blacklisting and whitelisting SFTP requests

Tags: sftp

I see that the sftp-server and internal-sftp support blacklisted and whitelisted protocol requests, however, I don't understand what exactly can be passed to those arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Ah, sorry, nevermind:

`/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -Q requests
open
close
read
write
lstat
fstat
setstat
fsetstat
opendir
readdir
remove
mkdir
rmdir
realpath
stat
rename
readlink
symlink
posix-rename
statvfs
fstatvfs
hardlink
fsync`