# SFTP - whitelisting requests for read-only access

Tags: ssh, redhat, sftp

I am trying to white-list certain SFTP requests so that a user can only open and read files and folders. Currently I have this, based on this [thread](https://serverfault.com/a/700908/247455):

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match User my-read-user
    ChrootDirectory /sftp/%u
    ForceCommand internal-sftp -p open,close,read,opendir,stat,readdir,fstat,lstat,statvfs,fstatvfs,readlink,realpath
```

This seems to work fine - with one exception: I can create files though I cannot put any content in them. Kind of like `touch` would work?!

Any ideas are appreciated! Also any better approach would be fine :) Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Oh, I just found the - apparently - best [solution](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Server#The_SFTP_Server_Subsystem): The parameter -R sets the whole session into read-only mode.

```
Match User my-read-user
    ChrootDirectory /sftp/%u
    ForceCommand internal-sftp -R
```